# Recyclerview create each child-view as a separate bitmap

Tags: android

I want to create bitmap for all recyclerview items. following code are working only for visible items. If I scroll manually then it able to capture.

I want to do without scrolling. Any one can help please..

```
View u = holder.ll;
holder.ll.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(595, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(824, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
                u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                int totalHeight = holder.ll.getMeasuredHeight();
                int totalWidth = holder.ll.getMeasuredWidth();
                u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
                u.buildDrawingCache(true);
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
                bitmaps.add(b);
                u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Will add these in pdf and print as an invoice..

Comment: RecyclerView default only creates a few items and the rest are only created on scroll. You can search for a post on how to get all RecyclerView items without scrolling. You can also just create you're own list. You would then hopefully be able to loop through all items. It looks like you're doing a ViewHolder which won't have views until they're loaded into it. Maybe if you do get all items created it will just work.